Searching for an Integer with the highest index within a string - C#
String[] digits = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
String line = "four95qvkvveight5";

index_digit2 = digits
    .Where(d => line.Contains(d))
    .Max(d => line.IndexOf(d));

I am iterating over a file searching for the first and the last digit in each line. This is what I'm using to search for the last integer in each line, which is working fine until I reach the string you see above. Because i'm getting the index of the first 5, not the last. (index_digit2 = 5 not like I'm expecting 16)
I'm confused why it is like that and if there is a quick fix.
In all other cases this works pretty fine, as far as I could check.

There is LastIndexOf which you should have used. But I'd actually recommend to reconsider your approach. There are much more efficient ways to do this.

IndexOf => "Reports the zero-based index of the first occurrence of the specified Unicode character in this string.", LastIndexOf => "Reports the zero-based index position of the last occurrence ..." and there's actually also LastIndexOfAny that spares you the where clause.

For the sake of this question, are you not considering 95 to be a single integer, but two integers (9 and 5)?

^^ Right, that's contradictory. You speak of both "searching for the first and the last digit in each line" and right in the next sentence "to search for the last integer in each line" - which is a different task, actually.

Okay i`m searching for single digits - not integers. And I think LastIndexOfAny() is a very quick solution^^

As I said in the second comment: Consider LastIndexOfAny - that'll boil it down to line.LastIndexOfAny(digits);

... and make yourself familiar BenchmarkDotnet. You will want to give that some iterations of measureable improvements.

You might also want to consider char.IsDigit.

I'd just iterate the characters in your string from back to start:
int? index = null;
for(int i = myString.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if(myString[i].IsDigit())
    {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}

or a bit shorter:
var result = myString.Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Char = x }).LastOrDefault(x => x.Char.IsDigit())?.Index;

or using string.LastIndexOfAny:
var result = myString.LastIndexOfAny(digits);


This should do the job. It found the fifth position so it returns 5.
String[] digits = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
String line = "four95qvkvveight5";
var index_digit2 = digits
    .Where(d => line.Contains(d))
    .Max(d => line.LastIndexOf(d));
Console.WriteLine(index_digit2);

